# Calculating This Limit Question w/o L'Hospital

Tags: calculus, limits, discrete-mathematics, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x+5}-\sqrt[3]{5}}{x} = \frac{1}{3 \cdot 5^{2/3}}$$

I need to solve this without L'Hospital and I need something like $x^{1/3} = t^3$ or etc.

I need to use $a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, use it. Set $a=\sqrt[3]{x+5}$ and $b=\sqrt[3]{5}$.

Comment: use derivative definition

Comment: Was this actually in a contest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solutions have been posted that (i) recognize the limit as a derivative and (ii) rationalize the numerator.  We proceed, therefore, to present another way forward.

Here, we use the [Generalized Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalisations) to write

$$\begin{align}
(x+5)^{1/3}&=5^{1/3}\left(1+\frac x5\right)^{1/3}\\\\
&=5^{1/3}\left(1+\frac{x}{15}+O(x^2)\right)\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Using $(1)$ yields

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{(x+5)^{1/3}-5^{1/3}}{x}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}5^{1/3}\left(\frac1{15}+O(x)\right)=\frac{1}{3\cdot 5^{2/3}}}$$

as expected!

Answer (score 2):

As you already know which identity to use its pretty much trivial.

$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{((x+5)^{1/3}-5^{1/3})((x+5)^{2/3}+5(x+5)^{1/3}+5^{2/3})}{x((x+5)^{2/3}+5(x+5)^{1/3}+5^{2/3})}=\dfrac{1}{5^{2/3}+5^{2/3}+5^{2/3}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Why would anyone even try L'Hopital? The limit is just the definition of the derivative of $f(x) = (x+5)^{1/3}$ at $0.$